# output jquery form values into html css box

Tags: jquery, html

maybe someone can help me with a problem i'm having. I have captured some form fields as follows:

```
var $inputs = $('#details :input');
```

and now i need to output some of them into a html box i've coded that has room for things like name, email etc. These aren't formfields, just normal html.css.

i don't know how to get the values out of the `$inputs` variable, i'm new to jquery and been trying really hard to get it to work.

any help appreciated.

Comment: can someone correct me if i'm wrong but it looks as if you're declaring a PHP vaiable? Can you not just do var inputs?

Comment: Yes you can, but that works also :)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the jQuery set invoking `.each()`<sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/each/)</sup> and access each element individually from within the loop:

```
var $inputs = $('#details input');

$inputs.each(function(index, elem) {
     $('#your_html_box_id').append(elem.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('input').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```